# Измерять временные интервалы непрерывно

Tags: многопоточность

Опыт еще не большой. Собрал на УНО 3  датчик кода Морзе (даже несколько вариантов). Хочу сделать автоматический прием кода. Когда-то делал такой аппаратным способом на логике. Для этого надо непрерывно измерять как длительность импульсов, так и промежутков. А на основании этих измерений происходит дешифрация кода Морзе. Если нагрузить Дуню на измерения временных интервалов, то откуда взять ресурсы на остальной анализ? Похоже без дополнительной аппаратной части не обойтись. Если я не прав, то надеюсь старшие товарищи меня поправят.

Comment: Если ваш код передается по одной цифровой линии в виде сигналов логического нуля и единицы - ставьте обработчики прерываний для входа. И в обработчиках вы будете иметь информацию типа "время 1200 мс, переход 0-1".

Comment: Спасибо буду обмозговывать.